# Get annotation on bean method

Tags: java, spring-boot

Im trying to get the annotation of the methods on my beans, but the annotation list return empty. Here's how I'm doing it.

```
@PostConstruct
public void findSensitiveAnnotations(){
    Map<String,Object> beans = applicationContext.getBeansWithAnnotation(RestController.class);
    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : beans.entrySet()){
        for (int i=0 ; i<entry.getValue().getClass().getDeclaredMethods().length ; i++){
            System.out.println(entry.getValue().getClass().getDeclaredMethods()[i]);
            for (Annotation a : entry.getValue().getClass().getDeclaredMethods()[i].getAnnotations()){
                System.out.println(a.toString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The first `System.out.println()` prints things like:

```
public final org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity com.company.product.web.rest.AccountResource$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$dff83dd3.sendResetEmail(java.lang.String,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
```

But the second `System.out.println()` is never called, annotation list length == 0.

Here is the method example corresponding to `sendResetEmail(@RequestParam String email, HttpServletRequest request)`

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/reset/byEmail",
    method = RequestMethod.POST,
    produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@Timed
@Sensitive
public ResponseEntity<String> sendResetEmail(@RequestParam String email, HttpServletRequest request) {...}
```

My Annotation:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface Sensitive { }
```

Comment: The annotaiton need to have @Retention(RUNTIME) to be visible trough reflection.

Comment: @MarcosVasconcelos, sorry. I failed to add my annotation code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The getBeansWithAnnotation seems not to return the real class name.

Try to do something like that:

```
Map<String,Object> beans = applicationContext.getBeansWithAnnotation(Service.class);
    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : beans.entrySet()){
        Class<?> clazz = entry.getValue().getClass();
        //System.out.println(clazz.getName());
        String[] split = clazz.getName().split("\\$");
        String realClassName = split[0];
        //System.out.println(realClassName);
        Class<?> myClass = getClass().getClassLoader().loadClass(realClassName);
         Method[] methods = myClass.getDeclaredMethods();
        for(Method method: methods) {
            for (Annotation a : method.getAnnotations()){
                System.out.println(a.toString());
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yep, it was that `$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$623cfd77` after the class name that caused the problem

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to call `getDeclaredAnnotations()` instead of `getAnnotations()`